# How do I create a path shortcut?

Tags: directory, shortcuts

I have a very beginner question. I would like to create a shortcut to a directory that is global so that when I do something like

```
cd $dir
```

It will take me to the specified directory. Or if I am prompted to specify a download path in some program I can just input $dir into the field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep the path of that directory in a [global variavble](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html). For example:

```
export DIR="/path/to/directory"
```

To make the change permanently, add the above line to your `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use symbolic links. Advantages:

- It will work in all applications, rather than just your shell.
- If you change or add shortcuts, it will immediately update everywhere, rather than having to restart applications before they see the new environment variable.

To do this, I have a directory to contain my shortcuts:

```
$ mkdir ~/_
$ ln -s /path/to/dir ~/_/dir
```

Then I can refer to the directory as `~/_/dir`. You can also create more shortcuts, e.g. `ln -s /media/username/backup_disk/backups ~/_/bak`.

If you're the only human user on your computer, save a keystroke by creating the shortcut directory higher:

```
$ sudo mkdir /_
$ sudo chown username: /_
$ ln -s /path/to/dir /_/dir
```